# How to properly get the value of Mobx @observable in TypeScript?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, store, mobx

I have a store class which has a property:

```
@observable customObject: customObject[] = [];
```

If I wanted to get the value of this observable would I make a method in the same class with:

**Option 1**

```
getCustomObject(): Observable<CustomObject[]> {
     return this.customObject;
}
// the observable I'm using would be imported from "rxjs" and not "mobx"
```

**Option 2**

```
getCustomObject() {
     return this.customObject;
}
// How can I subscribe to this observable when the method doesn't return an observable?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According To Ang4 or 6
Use

```
 getCustomObject(): Observable<CustomObject[]> {
     return this.customObject;
}
```

And import observable from rxjs

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `Observable.of();` like this:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

getCustomObject(): Observable<CustomObject[]> {
     return Observable.of(this.customObject);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of mobx-utils towork with RxJs as mentioned in [mobx FAQs](https://mobx.js.org/faq/faq.html).

So, lets assume you have store class, then, you can add a method that returns RxJs `Observable` as shown below:

```
import { observable } from 'mobx';
import * as mobxUtils from 'mobx-utils';

import { Observable, of, from } from 'rxjs';

...


class Store {
    @observable customObject: any = [];

    rxjsObservable(): Observable<any[]> {
      return from(mobxUtils.toStream(() => this.customObject));
    }
}
```

To use it, you can subscribe and use the values.  Example below:

```
  let store = new Store();

  store.rxjsObservable().subscribe((c) => {
    console.log("Received new value:", c);
  })

  store.customObject = [1,2,3];
  // Console will print 
  // => Received new value: [1, 2, 3]
```

PS: Example uses RxJs 6.  If older version of RxJs, then, `from` may have to replaced with `Observable.from`.